# Running a script on multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to make a script that launches on several bases to give Microsoft this located on the same server.
(knowing that new databases are created every month)
In the best of worlds, the result would have to be exported in CSV in one or more CSV files

Here is the query SQL:

```
SELECT [CT_Num]
      ,[CT_Intitule]
      ,[CG_NumPrinc]
      ,'INFO_L100'
  FROM [dbo].[F_COMPTET]

where ct_type = 1 and ct_sommeil = 0
```

I had another hypothesis but it only runs on the master database and does not save the result

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(255);
SET @command='select CT_Num ,CT_Intitule ,CG_NumPrinc FROM [dbo].[F_COMPTET]'
EXEC SP_msforeachdb @command
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't assume the entire user base is male; part of the agreements you agreed to when signing up is using gender neutral language unless someone asks you otherwise. There are not just men that are taking their time to answer questions here.

Comment: Dale please excuse me I do not master English perfectly yet. I am very respectful of every human

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `USE` command to set the database context and an `IF` to omit system databases:

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(255);
SET @command='USE [?];IF DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''SSISDB'') select CT_Num ,CT_Intitule ,CG_NumPrinc FROM [dbo].[F_COMPTET];';
EXEC SP_msforeachdb @command;
```